# AngularJS v1.3.x Email Validation Issue

Tags: angularjs, validation, email

Sample email: some@mail

In Angular v1.1.x this email is not valid. But in Angular v1.3.x it's valid. I know technically it's valid but I need like some@valid.com email. I tried some regex but not worked.

How can I change validation in Angular v1.3.x ?

Comment: why is this technically valid? i've never seen an email like that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use ng-pattern in your email input.

```
<input type="email" name="input" ng-model="text" ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,15})$/" required>
```

See an example: [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XZ03YcPYMsp9MNzv0UZU?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Now this got even better, Angular 4 has email validator built-in, there is no boilerplate code needed :)

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-6
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13709

Just add **email** to the  tag. For example

```
  <form #f="ngForm">
    <input type="email" ngModel name="email" required email>
    <button [disabled]="!f.valid">Submit</button>
    <p>Form State: {{f.valid?'VALID':'INVALID'}}</p>
  </form>
```