# Require two words in textbox, with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-pattern

I really struggling with this. I need to force the user to write the first and last name, in only one textbox.
I using AngularJS, and I want to validate text field using ng-pattern. The field should accept all characters, and **require 2 words**.
This is input:

```
<input name="fistname_lastname" ng-model="fistname_lastname" ng-pattern='my_pattern' type="text">
```

I have the my pattern in the controller, like this:

```
$scope.my_pattern = /^\s*\w*\s*$/;
```

Is there another better way do it.

Comment: try this `/^(.*?[a-zA-Z]){2,}$/`

Comment: "Is there a better way"? The word Better is very suggestive, would you mind rephrasing that? You haven''t told us what's wrong with your solution at its current state. Why do you feel it is not working to your satisfaction? Please include the actual behaviour, and your desired behavior with example output.

Comment: Yes, you are right. What I meant was, if is possible or better to use, another solution like html5 to do what I need. Require the user, to insert first and last name into one textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, for all your help. But what really worked was this regular expression.

```
\b([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,30}[- ]{0,1}|[A-Z]{1}[- \']{1}[A-Z]{0,1}  
[a-z]{1,30}[- ]{0,1}|[a-z]{1,2}[ -\']{1}[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,30}){2,5}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it by [directive too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28431112/2435473), but just for validating just text contains two characters or not `ng-pattern` would be better way to do.

Here your html would be using `(.*?[a-zA-Z]){2,}` this pattern.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="fistname_lastname" max-length="30" 
ng-pattern="/^(.*?[a-zA-Z]){2,}$/" placeholder="add new todo here"/>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13511/)

**Update**

If you want to stop your form from submitting,, then you need to no worry about it. Angular internally manages this for you. Whenever you mention `ng-pattern` against any form field, angular creates object for that field (field should have `name` and `ng-model` attribute), that object is responsible for the validity of particular field. As as `ng-pattern` regx doesn't gets satisfied, angular make that field as `invalid`, means it append  `ng-invalid-pattern` & `ng-invalid` class. Resultant the form also gets invalid. and now if you can look at form object you will find that form gets `invalid` by using syntax `form.$valid` on html.

**HTML**

```
<form name="form" ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstname_lastname"  size="30" ng-pattern="/^(.*?[a-zA-Z]){2,}$/" placeholder="add new todo here"/>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.submit = function(){
    if($scope.form.$invalid) //here you can stop use from submitting for by checking validity
        alert('Form is invalid'); //form is invalid
    else
         alert('Form is valid');//here you can do actual submit to server
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/13610/)

Hopefully this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that pattern works for what I need. But I'm still struggling the validation part. After submitting the form, how can i use this pattern to stop  the submission?

Comment: write `ng-submit="submit()"` method which will call when you submit the form then inside that method use `if($scope.form.$valid) //submit the form usning ajax else alert("please fill required fields.");`

Comment: Thank you for the help.The submission part, its working, but the pattern is not. In your example, its always validate the textbox.

Comment: @Liam check my updated Fiddle in answer..now everything will work properly