# html5 validation in Ionic

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am learning Ionic at the time. But it seems like HTML5 validation is not working in Ionic.

So, i have a login form like below.

```
<h3> Login </h3>
<form>
        <input name="emailaddress" placeholder="Enter Email Address" class="email" [(ngModel)]="userData.l_email" type="email" required />
            <input name="name" placeholder="Enter Password" class="name" type="password" [(ngModel)]="userData.l_password" required />

    <button class="semi-transparent-button is-blue with-border" (click)="login()">
  Login
</button>
</form>
```

When i click on login button it didn't perform validation. As i have put required in both field but it simply submit the form.

Also email validation is not working.

I have checked [How can I make validation of email in Ionic using HTML5, JS or Angular work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835533/how-can-i-make-validation-of-email-in-ionic-using-html5-js-or-angular-work) but it is a work around. That i want to avoid.

Comment: What is the component code for the validation?

Comment: In HTML 5 form i don't think we need to define anything. It works automatically. Do i need to define validation code for form in Ionic.

Comment: HTML5 validation will work on a submit button, you've used a standard button with angular binding to he click event, they are not the same thing

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 form validation does not work in Ionic. Instead, you can use Angular forms.

[This is a great tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/advanced-forms-validation-in-ionic-2/) by Josh Morony on how to do it.

In your case, you can do something like this using `FormBuilder` and specifying `Validators` for each field (for a full list of available validators, take a look at [the docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators)).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class Login {
  login: FormGroup;
  submitted: boolean = false;

    constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.login = this.formBuilder.group({
        email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.email, Validators.required])],
        password: ['', Validators.required],
      });
    }

    onLogin() {
      this.submitted = true;

      if (this.login.valid) {
        console.log(this.login.value);
      }
   }
}
```

In your template, use `FormGroup` and show your error message when the field is invalid.

```
<form [formGroup]="login" (ngSubmit)="onLogin()">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <p ion-text [hidden]="login.controls.email.valid || submitted === false" color="danger" padding-left>
    Please enter a valid email
  </p>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <p ion-text [hidden]="login.controls.password.valid || submitted === false" color="danger" padding-left>
    Password is required
  </p>

    <button ion-button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try.