# Form Validation Not Working on IONIC but working on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-v1

I have to provide mandatory fields validation in my ionic app. But, i am not being able to get the default angular form validation working. I used ng-submit but in ionic that's not even firing the submit.
Is there a directive that i can use

```
<ion-view title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="has-header padding">
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="DashCtrl">
      <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="red" required>  Red <br/>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="green" required> Green <br/>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="color" value="blue" required> Blue <br/>
      <tt>color = {{color | json}}</tt><br/>
      <button type="submit" ng-click="submitForm()">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

But, if its an AngularJS app, its working as expected

AngularJS Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/EdItU2IIkO1KIsC052Xx?p=preview

IONIC Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/tr7btg7mr0SHhbOB?p=preview

Comment: In the IONIC, the code uses the `ng-click` directive on the submit button. In the AngularJS, the code uses the `ng-submit` directive on the `<form>` element. The IONIC uses `required`; the AngularJS uses `ng-required`. Apples to oranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTML5 not working in Ionic check maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45005887/11694892) answer from [html5 validation in Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44994189/5535245)

But, you can do this as well:

change your submit with `ng-click="submitForm(myForm)"`

and your submit function like this

```
   $scope.submitForm = function(form) {
     if (form.$valid == true){
       console.log('yay')
     } else {
       console.log('Nyay')
     }
    };
```

forked your plnkr with this changes, check it [HERE](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/dvI0q3j4oR1TfWyd)

Hope it helps!

Comment: [Avoid uninformative links](http://stephanieleary.com/2015/05/why-click-here-is-a-terrible-link-and-what-to-write-instead/)