# Typescript: How to write long regexp in 2 lines

Tags: regex, typescript

I use tslint and when I write long regexp in typescript

```
var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

I got error - exceeds maximum line length of 140.

Does anybody know how to write it in 2 lines. I can do that with a hack. But I'm not satisfied with this solution.

```
    var r1 = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))/;
    var r2 = /@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    var re = new RegExp(r1.source + r2.source);
```

Comment: How is that related to Angular2?

Comment: Also check [Casimir's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561010/angular-internet-routable-email-address-validation#comment58811760_35561678) regarding a similar email validation regex.

Comment: I use angular2-seed boilerplate app. And tslint settings are pre-set there.

Comment: Yes this is duplicate [How to split a long regular expression into multiple lines in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317049/how-to-split-a-long-regular-expression-into-multiple-lines-in-javascript) Still I hoped that more elegant solution exists

Answer (score 3):

Why not use strings?

```
var r1 = "^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))";
var r2 = "@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$";
var re = new RegExp(r1 + r2);
```

RegExp(string) is easier for modification and/or dynamically generated regex